# If tomcat down make apache serve another page

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have a tomcat instance linked to Apache Http Server. What I am looking for is, if I stop my tomcat service for a while for like deploying new version of web application or some other reason, then my apache recognizes that tomcat is down then it serve some other static page saying "sorry, we are down for maintenance" , is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

When Apache fails to forward a request to a Tomcat instance, it will respond with a HTTP status code 500. You can provide a custom [ErrorDocument](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html) instead, containing your maintenance message.